# Grouping multiple rows of addresses to show latest row only

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following SQL to get information from my database table `check_in`

```
SELECT checkin_id, checkin_client_id, checkin_inventory_id, checkin_property_id, checkin_date, client_username, property_address_line_1, property_town, property_county, property_postcode, property_type, property_rooms, client_first_name, client_last_name, client_organisation_name, client_unique_id, checkin_passcode
FROM check_in ci
INNER JOIN properties pr
    ON ci.checkin_property_id = pr.property_id
INNER JOIN clients cl
    ON ci.checkin_client_id = cl.client_id
WHERE client_unique_id LIKE ? OR client_first_name LIKE ? OR client_username LIKE ? OR client_organisation_name LIKE ? OR property_address_line_1 LIKE ?
```

Which works fine, it brings back all the rows that match the search term, however, it is likely that results will have the same address linked to them, but are newer date wise (`checkin_date`). I only want to show the most recent row for each address (`property_address_line_1`), what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below, I added a subquery to limit the results to the latest check-in at each property.

```
SELECT checkin_id,
       checkin_client_id,
       checkin_inventory_id,
       checkin_property_id,
       checkin_date,
       client_username,
       property_address_line_1,
       property_town,
       property_county,
       property_postcode,
       property_type,
       property_rooms,
       client_first_name,
       client_last_name,
       client_organisation_name,
       client_unique_id,
       checkin_passcode
  FROM check_in ci
 INNER JOIN properties pr
    ON ci.checkin_property_id = pr.property_id
 INNER JOIN clients cl
    ON ci.checkin_client_id = cl.client_id
 WHERE checkin_date =
       (select max(ci2.checkin_date)
          from check_in ci2
         where ci2.checkin_property_id = ci.checkin_property_id)
   and (client_unique_id LIKE ? OR client_first_name LIKE ? OR
       client_username LIKE ? OR client_organisation_name LIKE ? OR
       property_address_line_1 LIKE ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "group by" all of the columns that uniquely constitute an address (address_line_1 and property_postcode should do it) and display the MAX(checkin_date):

```
SELECT checkin_id, checkin_client_id, checkin_inventory_id, checkin_property_id, MAX(checkin_date), client_username, property_address_line_1, property_town, property_county, property_postcode, property_type, property_rooms, client_first_name, client_last_name, client_organisation_name, client_unique_id, checkin_passcode
FROM check_in ci
INNER JOIN properties pr
ON ci.checkin_property_id = pr.property_id
INNER JOIN clients cl
ON ci.checkin_client_id = cl.client_id
WHERE client_unique_id LIKE ? OR client_first_name LIKE ? OR client_username LIKE ? OR client_organisation_name LIKE ? OR property_address_line_1 LIKE ?")
GROUP BY address_line_1, property_postcode
```

Comment: I have 2 checkins for the same address, one has an id of 78, one has an id of 79, when i use your code, it is only selecting id 78, which is older than 79. Do you know why?

Comment: id 78 has a date of `2014-07-20 16:00:09` where id 79 has a date of `2014-07-20 17:55:25`. It's still choosing the older one?

Comment: Are you able to help Ron?

Comment: Does the checkin_date have a datetime data type?

Comment: I made a simple mock-up of the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6832f4/1 and it returns the latest date/time?

Comment: yeah im using datetime data type but it's not selecting the most recent one, always the oldest